# Vagrant faied to create host only adapter

Tags: cakephp, vagrant, host

I have just git cloned cakebox to my c drive and then then did what the documentation says to copy the .yaml file and then select vagrant up.  When I did that then I get a 0x80004005 error and saying that failed to create host-only adapter.

I have windows 10, the latest version of vagrant and the latest version of virtualbox.  I installed windows 10 yesterday. I installed virtualbox and then install vagrant.  then did the command to get cakebox.  I have seen other posts on here that says to restart virtualbox but that is only on mac os x and linux.  How can I fix this issue so I am able to get it working for cake3

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead

Comment: It is a known issue, more info here: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/1015 https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040 We have to wait for the new release...

Comment: I have had no issues with this before.  I reverted back to old versions of vagrant and virtualbox and still get the same error.  I had the cakebox working fine and I was just starting up the vm and that is when it gave me that error.  I had it fine on windows 8.1.  I upgraded to Windows 10 and now it does not work at all.